# Nested map creation from a list and a map in terraform

Tags: terraform, amazon-vpc

Given the following list of azs and map of networks, I need to create a map using local.azs as keys and the local.networks as the values. Since nested for statements aren't possible, this is tricky. I'd include the code I've already tried but it'd probably cause more confusion than guidance.

```
local.azs = [ "us-east-1", "us-east-2"]
local.networks = {
   mgmt = "10.0.0.0/24",
   web = "10.10.0.0/24"
}
```

Desired result would look like:

```
private_subnets = {
  us-east-1 = {
    mgmt = "10.0.0.0/24"
    web = "10.0.0.0/24"
  }
  us-east-2 = {
    mgmt = "10.0.0.0/24"
    web = "10.0.0.0/24"
  }
}
```

Ultimately, the goal is to iterate over this data within the context of an aws-vpc resource declaration,

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample code.

```
locals {
  azs = [ "us-east-1", "us-east-2"]
  networks = {
   mgmt = "10.0.0.0/24",
   web = "10.10.0.0/24"
  }
}

output "private_subnets" {
  value = {for az in local.azs : az => local.networks }
}
```

Test:

```
$ terraform plan

Changes to Outputs:
  + private_subnets = {
      + us-east-1 = {
          + mgmt = "10.0.0.0/24"
          + web  = "10.10.0.0/24"
        }
      + us-east-2 = {
          + mgmt = "10.0.0.0/24"
          + web  = "10.10.0.0/24"
        }
    }
```